# Grid shows whitespace area

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs7

I'm facing a problem, where a grid with buffered renderer can show a large whitespace area after reloading the store. I found this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/e6e&view/editor) in the sencha forum describing the problem. This is still happening in 6.7 and 7.0. Is there any known solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is potentially caused by the reload mechanism you used. The newer documentation of [Ext.view.Table.refresh](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.view.Table.html#method-refresh) states that it should ony be used when the bufferedRenderer is set to false. [Older versions](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.view.Table.html#method-refresh) don't contain this hint.

The fiddle seems to be fixed when I use

`grid.getStore().reload()`

instead of

`grid.getView().refresh()`

in the go-button-handler.

Greetings

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!